# Problems with saving and reading variables to session in asp.net mvc controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, session

I want to store a simple variable in the session, to be able to get its value from different controllers.

In my controller I've tried to save variable this way:

```
HttpContext.Session.Add("CurrentPage",index.ToString())
```

And this way:

```
Session["CurrentPage"] = index.ToString();
```

But when I'm trying to read from session: 
`var currPage = Session["CurrentPage"]` I am getting nothing. Variable is not initialized and isn't displayed in Locals debug window.

What am I doing wrong?

For now I've decided to use cookies for that task, but anyway I am interested in possible solutions. May be someone else will have same problem and will search the solution.

Comment: looks correct to me. Are you sure your session isn't getting invalidated in between setting and reading your variable?

Comment: @Tom How to check, if my session is getting invalidated?

Comment: http://www.tyronedavisjr.com/2008/11/23/detecting-session-timeouts-using-a-aspnet-mvc-action-filter/

Answer (score 0):

If u want to pass a value from one method to another in a controller let try this

```
TempData["Data"] = index.ToString();
```

and to retrieve the data back
use

```
var message = TempData["Data"];
```

Comment: As I thought before, TempData is used to pass data in one reirect. If there are more redirects - TempData will be erased. In my case I will have more than one redirect between saving to TempData / Session and reading from it.